# Como alterar o estado de uma variável usando Express e EJS?

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

Estou tentando implementar um loader em minha aplicação da seguinte maneira:

```
1 - seto a variável isLoading para true

2 - faço as requests

3 - seto a variável isLoading para false
```

Com essa váriavel eu consigo fazer um if no front-end(EJS) para exibir ou não meu gif de loading.

O problema é o seguinte, pelo que vi a unica maneira de enviar uma variavel para o EJS é usando o `req.render` e se eu faço isso nas duas vezes que preciso alterar o estado da variável acabo tomando uma exception:

> (node:11752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client

Como posso resolver o problema?
Segue código:

**Express:**

```
router.get('/backup', AuthCheck, async (req, res) => {
    res.render('my-page', {
        isLoading: true,
    });

    await saveProduct();

    res.render('my-page', {
        isLoading: false,
    });
});
```

**EJS:**

```
<%if (isLoading) { %>
    <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
        <img style="width: 120px; height: 120px;" src="/imgs/loading.gif" />
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Essa lógica nunca irá funcionar, pois para cada requisição `HTTP`, só é possível enviar uma resposta, que é justamente o que o método `render` faz. Que tal repensar seu problema? Ao invés de gerar uma div com um loading no lado do servidor, não seria possível usar JavaScript para gerar e tratar essa div no lado do cliente?